# Very long Gnome login time

Tags: 10.04, gnome, performance, login

My machine is taking ages to get from the login screen after booting to actually showing the gnome desktop (as in, over a minute). It seems as though it is just waiting for a long period of that time . This has been a problem for a long time. The [bootchart](http://davidf.sjsoft.com/files/bootchart/golg-lucid-20101111-1.png) is available - any ideas on what is causing this? (Also on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/219275/very-long-login-time-in-lucid))

Comment: Mine too. Is it because of the capacity of RAM or the CPU?

Comment: I have 4GB of RAM and a Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5550 @1.83GHz. Surely that's reasonable?

Comment: this is a mystery we are all trying to solve (me included). disabling compiz and loading it after the desktop loads does speed it up a bit, but i stopped doing that when I realized that it also seems to have something to do with gconf, and quite honestly I don't want to start compiz when I log in every time :P

Comment: Should we point it out for the One Hundred Papercuts Project?

Comment: I don't think this is a papercut - it could have multiple causes for different users, and they aren't all necessarily easy to solve

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating/logging in with a diffent user account?
Can you verify that the same delay happens for all the user accounts?

Perhaps you could try to delete all the ~/.gnome* files and folders in order to be re-created from scratch.

You will lose of course all of your personal settings, but i think it deserves a chance..